# Zend update ... returning ... into

Tags: oracle, zend-framework

I've this query returning the new value by a bind variable:

```
update tab1 set counter=counter+1 where id = 7 returning counter  into :bind_var;
```

but no idea how to to it in zend, any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I take it you're using the `Zend_Db_Adapter_Oracle` adapter? As `Zend_Db_Statement_Oracle` uses `oci_bind_by_name()` internally, this can handle both IN and OUT parameters. For OUT parameters, you should always set the type.

Basically, you can simply do this with your statement

```
$stmt->bindParam('bind_var', $counter, SQLT_INT);
```